# Slicing: Out of bounds error in Go

Tags: go, slice

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := make([]int, 5)
    printSlice("a", a)
    b := make([]int, 0, 5)
    printSlice("b", b)
    c := b[1:]
    printSlice("c", c)
}


func printSlice(s string, x []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s len=%d cap=%d %v\n",
        s, len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

The above gives me an out of bounds error:

```
a len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]
b len=0 cap=5 []
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
   /private/var/folders/q_/53gv6r4s0y5f50v9p26qhs3h00911v/T/compile117.go:10 +0x150
```

Why is the slicing expression to create the `c` slice results in an error?

Answer (score 23):

**In short:** The problem is not with the lower bound which can be equal to or greater than `len()` (the upper limit is dictated by `cap()` in case of slices). The problem is with the **higher** bound: it must be greater than or equal to the lower bound. And since you didn't specify the higher bound, it defaults to `len()` (and not to `cap()`!) which is `0`. And `1` is not less than or equal to `0`.

[Spec: Slice expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

> For arrays or strings, the indices are *in range* if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity `cap(a)` rather than the length.

Since you are slicing a slice, indices are in range if:

```
0 <= low <= high <= cap(a)
```

So this line:

```
c := b[1:]
```

Is invalid, because:

> A missing low index defaults to zero; a missing high index defaults to the **length** of the sliced operand.

So in your case `low = 1` and `high = 0` (implicit), which does not satisfy:

```
0 <= low <= high <= cap(a)
```

So for example the following expressions are valid:

```
c := b[1:1]        // c len=0 cap=4 []
c := b[1:2]        // c len=1 cap=4 [0]
c := b[1:cap(b)]   // c len=4 cap=4 [0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: the problem gets trickier because if you use non-literal expressions (see https://go.dev/play/p/Yv5EX1QNRD-) then the compiler won't give a warning about lower > higher. At runtime this lack of compliance about slicing gets translated into a panic. Implicitly the expression `b[1:]` uses a non-literal expression (`len(b)` as icza highlight) for the higher bound and that, at the end, causes the panic. Just to add.