# In Go, why does a[1:] not give an index out of bounds error for a capacity = 1 slice?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Why does the following code *not* give a "slice bounds out of range" error?

```
a := []int{0}
a = a[1:]
fmt.Println(a) // []
```

Comment: Also related / interesting uncommon (edge) case: [Slicing: Out of bounds error in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859066/slicing-out-of-bounds-error-in-go/33859638#33859638)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [the Go specification for slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) states:

> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary expression
>
> a[low : high]
>
> constructs a substring or slice.
>
> ...
>
> For convenience, any of the indices may be omitted. A missing low index defaults to zero; a missing high index defaults to the length of the sliced operand:
>
> a[2:]  // same as a[2 : len(a)]
>
> ...
>
> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <= len(a), otherwise they are out of range.

In your case, `len(a)` is 1, and `a[1:]` is the same as `a[1:1]`, which means it is within range.