# Slice start position greater than length of the string

Tags: string, go, slice

Anyone knows why the code below runs without panic, it accesses the index one over the length of the string.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hi"[2:])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not slices "over" the length, 2 is exactly the length (equals to it).

> For arrays or strings, the indices are *in range* if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range.

Since you are slicing a `string`, indices are in range if:

```
0 <= low <= high <= len(a)
```

This expression:

```
"hi"[2:]
```

Since the upper bound is missing, it defaults to length, which is 2, so it is equvivalent to:

```
"hi"[2:2]
```

This is perfectly valid by the spec, and it will result in an empty `string`. If you change it to `"hi"[3:]`, then it will be out of range and result in a compile-time error (as slicing a constant `string` can be checked at compile-time).

Reasoning is that the upper bound is exclusive, e.g. `a[0:0]` is valid and will be 0-length, `a[0:1]` will have a length of 1, `a[0:len(a)]` valid and will have the same length as `a`.

In case of slices, the lower bound can even be greater than the slice length (but must not exceed the slice capacity). For more details, see [Slicing: Out of bounds error in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859066/slicing-out-of-bounds-error-in-go/33859638#33859638).